# leave blank space where author information will appear

Tags: spacing

Consider a snippet of text, the author information, that needs to be hidden for review. To allow organizing the space I would like to have a placeholder which uses up as much space as the author information will use up when rendered.

That is

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{test}
\author{information on authors}
text
\end{document}
```

My first attempt was to use `\textcolor{white}` which is inappropriate as it still allows to select the text in the final pdf file.

Is there a way to have the author information hidden (and not selectable in the final pdf) while it still uses the space it will use in the final version?

Comment: try `\author{\phantom{author name(s)}}`.

Comment: @tubilubi Can you include the author information (at least the size and format of it) that you are trying to suppress in your minimum working example?

Answer (score 2):

The author information is typeset in a one column `tabular` that's closed and reopened with the `\and` command.

So you can patch `\@maketitle` and `\and` so that the column typesets a phantom instead of the real entry.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox,collcell}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}
  {\begin{tabular}[t]{c}}
  {\begin{tabular}[t]{>{\collectcell\phantom}c<{\endcollectcell}}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\and} 
  {\begin{tabular}[t]{c}}
  {\begin{tabular}[t]{>{\collectcell\phantom}c<{\endcollectcell}}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{A title}
\author{A. U. Thor\\Department of Tetrapiloctomy\\University of Somewhere}
\date{}

\maketitle

Some text to see where the thing will appear and compare the results.

\end{document}
```

Here the example is with one author only, but the result should be as expected also with more authors.

Answer (score 1):

A space the size of the author name can easily be entered by using `\phantom':

```
\author{\protect\phantom{information on authors}}
```

The `\phantom` is "fragile" and needs to be `\protect`ed in this context.